# Prevent OkHttp/Retrofit from bypassing proxy

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

When OkHttp tries a proxy, and that route fails once, every request after that request will completely bypass the Android system proxy. So it is difficult to debug using Charles.

I currently have the code below, but it is setup to only be for Debug builds. It works great, but it's a hack, and we're looking to release this for all users.

Is there some hidden OkHttpClient.dontBypassProxy setting that I can't find? Or, does the code below look like a good solution?

```
    OkHttpClient.Builder baseClientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder().retryOnConnectionFailure(false).connectionPool(new ConnectionPool(5, 20, TimeUnit.SECONDS));

    //Ask OkHttp what proxies we have setup
    List<Proxy> proxies = ProxySelector.getDefault().select(URI.create("http://www.somesite.com"));

    if (proxies.size() > 0 && proxies.get(0) != Proxy.NO_PROXY) {
        //Force OkHttp to always use this proxy
        baseClientBuilder.proxy(proxies.get(0));
    }
```

Comment: Just curious: is this only a problem when you have two proxies?

Comment: It's just one proxy. I don't even know how to add two proxies in Android. So that's why the hack is to grab the first proxy it sees.

Comment: Could you isolate this into a failing test case? Here’s a sample: https://gist.github.com/swankjesse/981fcae102f513eb13ed

Comment: Sure, here's a test case. testForceProxy uses my force proxy hack, so it passes because the proxy isn't bypassed. While testBypassProxy uses a proxy selector. So it fails the test, because the proxy is bypassed and the connection succeeds. In testBypassProxy, I'd like to be able to tell the client to use the proxy if it exists, and not to try any other routes.

http://pastebin.com/iSCYwXmQ

Comment: I have the same issue. Every second try of the same request bypasses the proxy. I am on v3.2.0

Comment: @MikeOdie this is working as designed, though it’s possible we could change the design. The behavior of ProxySelector is inherited from HttpURLConnection, which you can verify with this test:
https://gist.github.com/swankjesse/240132f0d750a05d0380f32f7f822531
If you’d like to start a discussion on OkHttp’s issue tracker, please do.

Comment: Ok, great, thank you. I see what HttpURLConnection is doing. I'll file a feature request. In the meantime, do you think that my hack looks ok? It works fine in house, but I'm not sure if it's ready to go live.

https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2525

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed in OkHttp 3.5.0

https://square.github.io/okhttp/changelog_3x/

> OkHttp no longer attempts a direct connection if the system’s HTTP
>   proxy fails. This behavior was surprising because OkHttp was
>   disregarding the user’s specified configuration. If you need to
>   customize proxy fallback behavior, implement your own
>   java.net.ProxySelector.